# Write ORC using Pandas with all values of sequence None

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, orc

I want to write a simple dataframe as an ORC file. The only sequence is of an integer type. If I set all values to `None`, an exception is raised on `to_orc`.

I understand that `pyarrow` cannot infer datatype from `None` values but what can I do to fix the datatype for output? Attempts to use `.astype()` only brought `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Bonus points if the solution also works for

1. empty dataframes
2. nested types

Script:

```
data = {'a': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data) 
print(df)
df.to_orc('a.orc')  # OK
df['a'] = None 
print(df) 
df.to_orc('a.orc')  # fails
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
      a
0  None
1  None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ... line 9, in <module>
  ...
  File "pyarrow/_orc.pyx", line 443, in pyarrow._orc.ORCWriter.write
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 121, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unknown or unsupported Arrow type: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, see https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/30317. The problem is that the ORC writer does not yet support writing a column of all-nulls without specific dtype (not object dtype). If you cast the column to, for example, float first, then the writing works.

Using the `df` from your example:

```py
>>> df.dtypes
a    object
dtype: object

# the column has generic object dtype, cast to float
>>> df['a'] = df['a'].astype("float64")
>>> df.dtypes
a    float64
dtype: object

# now writing to ORC and reading back works
>>> df.to_orc('a.orc')
>>> pd.read_orc('a.orc')
    a
0 NaN
1 NaN
```